I'm trying to manage state using Bloc. but i keep getting this error "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used."
class FavouriteBloc extends Bloc<FavouriteEvent, FavouriteState> {
  FavouriteBloc() : super(FavouriteInitial()) {
    on<AddToFavorites>((event, emit) {
      List<HostelModel> hostelList = [];
      emit(FavouriteUpdated(hostelList.add(event.hostel)));
    });

    on<RemoveFromFavorites>((event, emit) {});
  }
}



sealed class FavouriteEvent {}

class AddToFavorites extends FavouriteEvent {
  final HostelModel hostel;

  AddToFavorites({required this.hostel});
}

class RemoveFromFavorites extends FavouriteEvent {
  final HostelModel hostel;

  RemoveFromFavorites({required this.hostel});
}

sealed class FavouriteState {}

final class FavouriteInitial extends FavouriteState {}

final class FavouriteUpdated extends FavouriteState {
  List<HostelModel> hostelList;

  FavouriteUpdated(this.hostelList);
}

I want to add this model data to the list using bloc. and later on use that list to populate a screen. im getting this error on the .add() method in the emit function. "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used"

If you look closely .add method return void (void add(E item)), this is why you are getting this error. FavouriteUpdated constructor expect a List of HostelModel.
You can add on previous like
 hostelList.add(event.hostel);
 emit(FavouriteUpdated(hostelList));

Or just feed on the constructor while there is nothing changes.
